# How to send json object from a Kafka consumer in .NET core and send it to Angular in real time using Web socket

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core, apache-kafka, websocket

I have created a WebSocket get API in .net core Which contains my kafka consumer.
[image]
I am consuming this API in the Angular application using
`import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";` npm package.

Now whenever i push some JSON on the producer I want it to appear on the consumer and then sent to the Angular using WebSocket connectivity

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as a [mcve], not an image